# Error: Could not connect to logcat in Android player xamarin visual studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Xamarin trial version and visual studio 2015 community version for trial at my end.

I started with a blank android application. It was running fine before.
but next day when i try to run it. Emulator is not runnig.

It is saying **Could not connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0**

I am attaching screenshot what errors i have in my logcat.
[image]

**Note-** I have disabled Fast deployment in my settings but its not working.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing emulator logs by running adb logcat -c in did the trick for me!!!